# Can't pass variable defined in main process to renderer BrowserView with contextIsolation enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a custom menu/title bar, but I'm adding it to the main BrowserWindow using a BrowserView, instead of just using the `BrowserWindow.loadURL()` method (for reasons).

This seems to cause problems with loading a preload script when context isolation is enabled though.

What I have:

main.js

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        contextIsolation: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
})

const bView = new BrowserView();
bView.setBounds(//set my bounds);
bView.webContext.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, "menu.html"));

mainWindow.setBrowserView(bView);
```

preload.js

```
const { remote } = require('electron')
window.mainWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

In the renderer script:

```
console.log(window.mainWindow); // undefined
```

I think I understand why it's undefined, but it's not clear to me how, if possible, to share a main process variable with a renderer process.

I've tried what's mentioned [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content) (using `webFrame.executeJavaScript()`) but that doesn't seem to do anything (and I'm not even sure what `webFrame` is supposed to be).

Everything works fine if I just load the menu.html using `mainWindow.loadURL(filePath)` but that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out my problem:

I was loading the preload script in the BrowserWindow. I needed to load it into the BrowserView instead and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

`contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` is interface to allow communicate between preload to renderer context when contextisolation is enabled. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#contextbridgeexposeinmainworldapikey-api-experimental

But also should note it won't able to forward non serializable object, possibly including remote object as well. Also exposing whole object via remote is great security hole defeats context isolation anyway, should be avoided. You may refer planned deprecation discussion about remote module too: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408